# password salting asp.net default page error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, web-applications

I was trying to salt password in asp.net web application mysql but its shows this error.While running getting the error.Please anyone tell me the error?

Error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
    Parser Error
    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'DemoPage.Default'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoPage.Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>

Source File: /Default.aspx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3163.0
```

Code default.aspx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebPage1
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader;
        String queryStr;
        String name;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoSQLQuery();
        }
        protected void submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
            conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();
            String queryStr = "";

            cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM webapp.userregistration WHERE username = @name  and password=@pas", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", usernameTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", passwordTextBox.Text);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            name = "";
            while (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
            {

                {
                    name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("username")) + " " + reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("password"));
                }

                //if the data matches the rows (username, password), then you enter to the page
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Session["uname"] = name;

                    Response.BufferOutput = true;
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx", false);

                }
                else
                {
                    passwordTextBox.Text = "invalid user";

                }
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }


        private void DoSQLQuery()
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                passwordTextBox.Text = e.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can `SELECT` by password then your login system is really not at all secure. You *must* use [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) at the absolute least, a password-specific hashing method. "Salting" is a method that fell out of style well over two decades ago.

Comment: How to use Bcrypt in this?

Comment: Search for "asp.net bcrypt" and there's dozens of examples.